# How to implement "show next highlight" in jquery.highlight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-highlightfade

I'm using `jquery.highlight.js` to highlight some keywords in `kendogrid`.
The size of the `kendogrid` is very large, so the highlighted keywords are missed easily while scrolling. I was thinking of adding a button on the grid, that will allow user to go to next highlighted keyword.
Any idea how to separate out the higlighted keywords?

Comment: can you provide link to the plugin you are using??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/master/jquery.highlight.js

Comment: @shubhamgupta.. Please give link which has documentation too not just js link!!

Comment: @TedNyberg i used the data from datasource of the grid and tried checking class(which highlights the keyords) of each word but no luck.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i found the plugin on github https://github.com/bartaz/sandbox.js there was no documentation though!

Answer (score 0):

Ok!! I've done some experiment for you and hope that will atleast fetch some idea to you.

Check this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/76kv6ank/)

```
$('.next').on('click',function(){
    var current=$('.hltxt').find('span.focus');
    var scrollToP;
    var scrollLefT;
    if($('.hltxt').find('span.focus').next('span.highlight').length===0)
    {
        scrollToP=$('.hltxt').find('.highlight:first').position().top-50
        scrollLefT=$('.hltxt').find('.highlight:first').position().left;
        $(current).removeClass('focus');
        $('.hltxt').find('.highlight:first').addClass('focus');
    }   
    else
    {
        scrollToP=$('.hltxt').find('span.focus').next('span.highlight').position().top
        scrollLefT=$('.hltxt').find('span.focus').next('span.highlight').position().left
        $(current).removeClass('focus').next('span.highlight').addClass('focus');
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop:scrollToP,
        scrollLeft:scrollLefT
    });

});
```

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :) Please note some additional classes that are added.. Let me know if any doubt!!